# Why when using the Facebook registration iFrame are all but one of the default fields missing?

Tags: facebook, iframe, registration

I'm trying to integrate Facebook registration into a website I'm working on using the default iFrame implementation:

Code taken from the official FB developer's page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=113869198637480&
         redirect_uri=[YOUR_REDIRECT_URI]
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

I've added my app's ID and modified the redirect_uri but for some inexplicable reason, the only thing that appears in the registration form is a box containing my name followed by the Register button. The fields birthday, gender, location and email are all missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I eventually figured this out.

I simply needed to add an ampersand (&) after the redirect URI, something which is not at all obvious and surely must be causing many people to pull their hair out like it was me.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
     client_id=113869198637480&
     redirect_uri=[YOUR_REDIRECT_URI]&
     fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
     scrolling="auto"
     frameborder="no"
     style="border:none"
     allowTransparency="true"
     width="100%"
     height="330">
</iframe>
```